Interval timer have sound
I'm currently making an interval timer app for exercise with the sound of counting 3 2 1 using Flutter.
I'm having difficulty solving the problem that when the user presses the home button or switches to another app, my app still runs and the sound still reads when finishing the exercise or moving to a new exercise. Does anyone have any solutions or keywords that can help me? Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
